# Sending JavaScript Array with Ajax to PHP returns Null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Am tryign to send a JS array to php but the post data keeps on returning null. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
console.log($Seats);
console.log($Seats.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify({ $Seats }));
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify($Seats);
 $.ajax({
    url     : 'database-files/addseatmaps.php',
    type    : 'POST',
    data    : {seater: jsonStr } ,
    success : function (data) {

    console.log(data);


    },error: function( error )
{
                                        //$("#loadingmessage").modal('hide');
$.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Submission Error','Check Internet Connection');
    submit.ladda( 'stop' );
                    },
    cache: false,
    processData: false,  
    contentType: false
    });
     return false;
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once("../classes/mysql.class.php");
session_start();

$insert = new MYSQL();
$busexist = new MySQL;

//echo date_default_timezone_get();

$d=strtotime("now");
$date =  date("d/n/Y H:i:s", $d);
$time =  date("H:i:s", $d);


$myArray = json_decode($_POST['seater']);

var_dump($myArray);
?>
```

here is the output i get :

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>D:\wamp64\www\lorrybus_admin\database-files\addseatmaps.php:22:
</small><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong, but i have tried everything possible still no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
processData: false,  
contentType: false
```

you need jquery to process your data to convert to the proper type(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and you need the content type to be set.

Comment: what does processData do also contentType and link to read would help

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , processData false means do not process what I pass to data, which means the object you passed will not be transformed into key=value pairs(you'd probably end up with something like `[object Object]`). with contentType false no content type will be explicity set by jQuery.ajax, so when your request reaches your server it wouldn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: got it. i really understand now. some of these documentations aren't as in depth as they should